# How to make a public but immutable variable (only outside) of a class in C++

Tags: c++, class

Rather than using a function that returns a class member, sometimes I can't do this and the compiler gives me an error with something like `Cxx11` error, or, `wpermissive address` when i try to refer to a function call. What avoids this is accessing the `public member` directly to use. But for the sake/reasoning of using `private` variables, where you can't change them outside the class's declaration, how can I get the best of both worlds? What I mean by this is be able to `access but not change` member variables. I can't use `const` as some of the variables are changed at runtime as a result of user inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Write an accessor. Along these lines:

```
class C {
private:
  int x_;
public:
  int x() const { return x_; }
};
```

Then you can access the member variable with `C c; c.x();`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225910/discussion-on-answer-by-igor-tandetnik-how-to-make-a-public-but-immutable-variab).